# How to project a point cloud into a 2D image (like Matlab scatter3d does)?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have a point cloud generated from a [Lidar](https://velodynelidar.com/lidar/products/brochure/HDL-64E%20S2%20datasheet_2010_lowres.pdf) sensor.

I'd like to project the 3D point cloud to a 2D image as if I were looking in the the eyes of the sensor (lets say for instance that the sensor reside on coordinate (0,0,0))

I'd like to generate a 2D image which looks very similar to the generated figure from Matlab (see below).

I know that this 3D to 2D projection lays in the in pin hole camera projection. However I failed to generate the same results as Matlab does. 
2nd question - beside I don't know which focal length should I set - because there is no actual focal length in point cloud.

[Here is the point cloud file](https://jmp.sh/PVHKNgK).

[Here is matlab generated figure](https://jmp.sh/BfvTdpW)

This is the destination image I'd like to generate:
[image]

Here is what I get:
[image]

Here is my Matlab code

```
path = fullfile(pwd, 'carPointCloud.txt');

data = importdata(path);
data(:,1:3) = data(:,1:3) - min(data(:,1:3)) + 1;
figure(5), scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),ones(1, size(data,1)), 
ones(size(data,1),1)); hold on;

resPixelToMeter = 100 / 1; 
focalPixels = 1;
imgWidth = 850;
imgHeight = imgWidth;
u = resPixelToMeter * focalPixels * (data(:,1) ./ data(:,3)) + imgWidth /2;
v = resPixelToMeter * focalPixels * (data(:,2) ./ data(:,3)) + imgHeight /2;

%figure(1), hist(u);
%figure(2), hist(v);

outOfImgRoi = u>imgWidth | v>imgHeight;
u(outOfImgRoi) = [];
v(outOfImgRoi) = [];

u = round(u);
v = round(v);

imgDim = [imgHeight, imgWidth];
indexes = sub2ind(imgDim, v, u);
img = zeros(imgHeight, imgWidth);

img(indexes) = 1;
figure(3), imshow(img);
```

Comment: If I undestand correctly, the first image is what you really want; so you should use `plot` function instead of generate a image (pure 2d image) and display it with  `imshow`.

Comment: That's true, however I want to create the image by myself in order to calculate the distance for each point.

Comment: Did you try that but without dividing by `data(:,3)`? That would give you a projection onto the x-y plane (i.e. the camera looking along the z-axis).

Comment: For any camera angle orthonormal to the standard basis you could simply omit the coordinates of one dimension as @Chris Luengo suggested. For any other camera angle you would need to apply an affine [basis transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) resulting in the desired view orthonormal to the new basis vectors, followed again by omitting the coordinates of one dimension